# Android Sqlite Find & Replace part string

Tags: android, sql, sqlite

I want to replace a part of my string in certain column of Sqlite table.

Eg: I have a table named "TABLE_EVENTS" having column "KEY_EPB".
The enties in column KEY_EPB are of the form

"ABC(100);CFG(200);"

"ABC(90)"

...

I want to replace say ABC by XYZ..so that the data in column KEY_EPB changes to

"XYZ(100);CFG(200)"

"XYZ(90)"

...

I found an answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10532656/sqlite-replace-part-of-a-string), but its not working for me.
What am I missing here?

CODE:

```
public void updateMember(String OldName, String NewName)
{
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase(); 
    String selectQuery = "UPDATE "+ TABLE_EVENTS +" SET " + KEY_EPB +" = replace(" + KEY_EPB + ", '" + OldName + "', '"+NewName+"') WHERE "+ KEY_EPB +" LIKE '%"+OldName+"%'";
    db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
    db.close(); ;   
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`rawQuery()` just compiles the SQL but doesn't run it. Use `execSQL()` instead.