# how to change file extension with an update statement?

Tags: android, sql, sqlite, sql-update

I have a table that stores images path but I realize that the extention is wrong. How can I change the extention? I am using SQLite database.

Example:

```
 Imagetable
 ----------
 /allimages/juan.gif
 /allimages/anthony.gif
```

I want to change it to:

```
 Imagestable
 ------------
 /allimages/juan.png
 /allimages/anthony.png
```

remeber that I have currently 6000 unique records and changing each one with a single update is not happening. I know I have to do an Update statement but not sure how to do it.

Comment: This answer might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10532656/sqlite-replace-part-of-a-string

Comment: Thank you, that example really help. Thank you once again.                                                                UPDATE table SET field = replace( field, 'C:\afolder\', 'C:\anewfolder\' ) WHERE field LIKE 'C:\afolder\%';