# SQLite: replace part of a string with another one

Tags: sqlite

I have a column named "tel". This column has some records that start with (for example) "0511" and I want to change it "0513". What is proper query?

Comment: Have you see that one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10532656/sqlite-replace-part-of-a-string?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use replace function

```
 UPDATE table SET tel= replace( tel, '0511', '0513' ) WHERE tel LIKE '0511%';
```

Check the SQLite core functions [here](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_corefunc.html)

**EDIT**
In case you have a match after the first 4 digits of your tel number.
For example 051121505113

```
  UPDATE table SET tel= replace(substr(tel,1,5), '0511', '0513' )||substr(tel,5) 
  WHERE tel LIKE '0511%';
```

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE table
SET tel = REPLACE(tell, '0511', '0513')
WHERE tel like '%0511%'
```

Answer (score 0):

In case there's a risk that '0511' exists within the rest if the string you can make sure to only replace 0511 at the start of the string like this:

```
UPDATE [table]
 SET [tel] = CASE WHEN 
  instr([tel], '0511') = 1  THEN 
    '0513' || substr([tel], 4)
  ELSE    
    [tel]
  END
WHERE [tel] LIKE '0511%';
```