# Android SQLite - replace part of a string safely

Tags: java, android, sqlite, android-sqlite

I need to rename tags in the task titles in database.
I saw similar questions [like this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10532656/sqlite-replace-part-of-a-string)
But in my app user could create a task with custom title. So the following solution could be dangerous:

```
db.execSQL("UPDATE " + Task.TABLE +
            " SET title = REPLACE(title, '" + fromTagName + "', '" + toTagName + "');");
```

What if user will create a task with some dangerous commands in the title (injection)? Will this approach crash? Is there alternative to use special android methods instead of raw SQL commands? Or is it safe as it is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use bind variables.  Simply place a ? where you have a variable, and pass an array of parmaeters, in order, to the rawQuery function.

You should NEVER use concatenation like you did above.  Use bind variables everywhere.  Anything user input should be in the bind variable, anything constant should be in the query.  That eliminates all possible SQL injection.

Comment: db.execSQL("UPDATE " + Task.TABLE +" title = REPLACE(title, '?', '?');", new Object[]{fromTagName, toTagName});
Something like this ?

Comment: @OleksandrAlbul for this overload of execSql() the documentation: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#execSQL(java.lang.String,%2520java.lang.Object%5B%5D) is clear: *Execute a single SQL statement that is NOT a SELECT/INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE*

Comment: @OleksandrAlbul My bad, as forpas said, you can't use execSQL for query, you need to use rawQuery() instead.  But the parameters and format are the same

Comment: @GabeSechan it is not a query, it is UPDATE statement. Thanks I have rewritten it with bind args.

Comment: @OleksandrAlbul An update is a query.  A query is any command to a db that effects or looks up data.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the [`update()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#update(java.lang.String,%2520android.content.ContentValues,%2520java.lang.String,%2520java.lang.String%5B%5D)) method with `ContentValues()`:

```
ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
cv.put("title", "new value");
int rows = db.update(Task.TABLE, cv, "id = ?", new String[] {String.valueOf(yourid)})
```

The 3d argument is the `WHERE` clause of the update statement and `?` is a placeholder for which you need to provide a value in the 4th argument.
So the statement is equivalent to:

```
UPDATE <Task.TABLE> SET title = 'new value' WHERE id = <yourid>
```

In the variable `rows` the method `update()` returns the number of rows that where updated.
This method is [sql-injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) safe.

Comment: In your example I need to to know the new value to replace the old value. But in my case the new value is build based on the old value by replacing the string. So I do not understand how could I use it in my case. It is only way to query cursor, proces a data in the java code, and use db.update to update the db, but it is overkilling.

Comment: *it is overkilling* maybe, but your question is about safety, right? You have to decide what you prefer.

Answer (score -1):

Use `DatabaseUtils.sqlEscapeString(stringToEscape)` to sanitize user input before inserting into database. Reference [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/DatabaseUtils.html#sqlEscapeString(java.lang.String)).

Comment: It has been drilled into me by others that simply escaping strings is not sufficient and to always used prepared statements and/or parameterized queries.  Of course it simply becomes a matter of trust if it is 3rd party code (not native to the DBMS), but the point of questioning such generic methods is whether they fully and properly escape strings for the **specific DBMS**.  Does it properly handle alternative string delimiters? What about multi-byte characters? Etc.

Comment: Its too easy to miss one of these, or to forget to unescape properly.  Use bind variables instead.

Comment: @CPerkins actually, the better phrase would have been "Reference" instead "Read more" thanks